# convert string into NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string, nsdate

i have a "DateTimeArray" this array contain

```
DateTimeArray[index 0] = 20.05.2011 12:12:50    
DateTimeArray[index 1]=  20.05.2011 12:13:20   
DateTimeArray[index 2]=  20.05.2011 12:20:10
```

all the value are in string,and i want to convert this string into NSDate and only want to access time not date
 and then this time values will be stored in array and this newly array will be used for drawing line chart

i hope some one know this issue

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code as follows,

```
for(int index=0;index<[DateTimeArray count];index++)
{
   NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *timeString=[[[DateTimeArray objectAtIndex:index]componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]objectAtIndex:1];
   NSDate *time=[df dateFromString:timeString];
   [timeArray addObject:time];
   [df release];
}
```

Comment: @KingofBliss, can you tell me how to set GMT+1, as it shows me 1 hour before time

Comment: [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+1"]];

Comment: still its not working, it shows me in debugger 1970-01-01 11:12:50 but real time is 12:12:50

Comment: I think your are printing the time value directly. I will print the date time value respective to your simulator timezone onle

Comment: Try this to verify,
for(int index=0;index<[timeArray count];index++)
{
   NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *timeString=[df stringFromDate:[timeArray objectAtIndex:index]];
   NSLog(@"%@",timeString);
}

Comment: i am doing , NSMutableArray *timeArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDate *time;
NSString *timeStamp;
   
for (NSMutableString *tString in DateTimeArray)
{
NSMutableArray *tArray=[[tString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
timeStamp =  [tArray objectAtIndex:1];  
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+1"]];   
time=[df dateFromString:timeStamp];
[timeArray addObject:time];
    
}

Comment: i verified with NSLog(@"%@",time); and it shows 1970-01-01 11:12:50 GMT which is 1 hour behind , real time is 12:12:50

Comment: NSDAte wont store the timeZone values, so if u print a raw NSDate it will print the date and time respective to your device/simulator timezone.

Comment: try by changing the timezone in simulator and you will know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *formattedDate = [df dateFromString:[DateTimeArray objectAtIndex:requiredIndex]];
[df release];
```

Comment: if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

Answer (score 1):

Best and cleaner approach:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

for(int i=0; i < [DateTimeArray count]; ++i)
{
   NSString *string = [DateTimeArray objectAtIndex:i];
   NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:string];
   [timeArray addObject:time];
}

[df release]; // ALWAYS release unused objects
```

Then to just access hours, and not days, you should select the required components of each `NSDate*` instance:

```
// Get the Gregorian calendar
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

// Get the date
NSDate* date = [timeArray objectAtIndex:my_index];

// Get the hours, minutes, seconds
NSDateComponents* hour = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSDateComponents* minute = [cal components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSDateComponents* second = [cal components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSMutableArray *nsdateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[DateTimeArray count]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    for(NSString *currentString in DateTimeArray){
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:currentString];
        [nsdateArray addObject:date];
    }
    [dateFormat release];
    NSLog(@"ArrayWithDate:%@",[nsdateArray description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the complete set of code.. Hope it helps..

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
int i=0;//start for{} loop
NSString *currDate = [formatter dateFromString:[DateTimeArray objectAtIndex:i]];
[formatter release];
```

Happy iCoding...

Comment: if format doesn't match the string you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:date];
or
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(kCFCalendarUnitHour | kCFCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```